# Can't find virtualenv installation during eb-cli setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, path, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, virtualenv, ebcli

I'm installing the Elastic Beanstalk CLI from Github on a Windows machine, but it keeps erroring out because of virtualenv. I get this error:

```
C:\Users\bigji\Bootcamp\NODE\ClassActivities\EB-CLI>python .\aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup\scripts\ebcli_installer.py

***********************************
1. Locating virtualenv installation
***********************************
ERROR: Could not find and "virtualenv" installed. Ensurevirtualenv is installed and that it is in PATH before executingthis script.

******************************************
2. Creating exclusive virtualenv for EBCLI
******************************************
'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've installed virtualenv, and can see it in the scripts folder from which I'm trying to run ebcli_installer. I've added the scripts folder, the virtualenv folder, and the folder containing virtualenv.exe to PATH (using edit environment variables), and I've searched other virtualenv problems on StackOverflow and not found anything that can help.

This is my first time with anything AWS, and my first time adjusting PATH. Can anyone suggest how to get the installer to find the virtualenv command?

Comment: Although I haven't got an answer to this, someone pointed me to Cloud9, the IDE for AWS environments, which doesn't require installation on the computer. I'm using that instead.
https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the install scripts [README](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup#user-content-23-troubleshooting) there are steps that should resolve your scenario.

Try running:

```
pip uninstall -y virtualenv
pip install virtualenv
python .\aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup\scripts\ebcli_installer.py
```

If this doesn't solve the issue some additional debugging will be necessary.

Comment: I did this before, but I tried it again just now and it worked. I don't know whether restarting the computer affected it, or what happened, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The troubleshooting steps did not solve the problem completely, because my virtualenv script was not added to my environmental PATH settings. I had to add the directory ./Python/Python39/Scripts manually, then restart and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image: CMD x Shell]

For those using windows, in prompt doesn't work but in shell does!

Answer (score 0):

On Debian/Ubuntu you can try:

```
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
```